# Nodejs : peerDependencies error while installing depedencNodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

In my attempt to get the libraries I need, npm install was working well till about a year and now as I move to a new server it breaks stating PeerDependencies error. I am kind of confused as I fail the reason for which the code is breaking, has any one faced a similar issue, It could not be because of older version of library being pre installed globally as I am moving to a new server totally. Any help here would be very well appreciated.

Error

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-49-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.10.37
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package karma does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-requirejs@0.2.2 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-mocha@0.1.10 wants karma@>=0.12.8
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-html2js-preprocessor@0.1.0 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-jasmine@0.1.5 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor@0.1.2 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-ng-scenario@0.1.0 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-script-launcher@0.1.0 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-karma@0.6.2 wants karma@~0.10.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-coffee-preprocessor@0.1.3 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.4 wants karma@>=0.9
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the `package.json` file with the appropriate versions of the npm packages. Uninstall first by running `sudo npm uninstall` and then update the `package.json`.

Run `npm list` to check the versions of the packages installed for your project. Try uninstalling the unmatched version package by providing the version too like

```
sudo npm uninstall karma@version.no
```